# How does Jenkins code coverage work?

Tags: python, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build and monitor the testing for my application.

I have such a piece of python code:

```
def register_os_handler():
    def handler(signal, frm):
        raise SystemExit()
    signal(SIGHUP, handler)
```

In my test, I create a subprocess, and send it a SIGHUP signal and it quits as expected, which means it reaches the line of `raise SystemExit()`.

When I submit it to Jenkins, all tests passed, but it says the line `raise SystemExit()` is not covered.

I feel curious that why that line was indeed reached, but still Jenkins complains?

1. How does the Jenkins' coverage report work?
2. If a process (even if it is a subprocess) quits, it cannot detect the line or take the line into account?
3. How to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Jenkins uses coverage.py. If you want to compute coverage for subprocess, you need a little hack, which is described here:

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html

Comment: thanks for the link. I am a python / Jenkins newbie. So can I configure my project in Jenkins so it does what the links say?

Comment: I don't know Jenkins well, but I see, you can add arbitrary shell code to the Jenkins job. So the simplest idea would be to use ``echo`` command to create the sitecustomize.py module.